# Bokeh plot first y-axis loses autoscale with second y-asix

Tags: bokeh

A simple bokeh plot, the first y-axis was originally auto-ranging.  With the added second y-axis, the first y-axis range is being affected.

I am unable to use a fixed y-axis range for either y-axis, because the limits are not known ahead of time.  I use an AjaxDataSource to update the data to the plot.

The following program demonstrates the problem.  Changing the values in `y3` will change the first y-axis range.

```
from numpy import sin
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, DataRange1d

x = [p/100 for p in range(0, 320)]
y = sin(x).tolist()

output_file("twin_axis.html")

p = figure()
p.line(x, y, color="red")

x1 = [0, 1.0, 2.2, 3.2]
y3 = [60, 70, 70, 70]  # Changing these values affects first y-axis scale
p.extra_y_ranges = {"Yield": Range1d(start=0, end=50)}  # tried DataRange1d(), no help
p.circle(x=x1, y=y3, color="blue", y_range_name="Yield")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Yield", axis_label="Yield(%)"), 'right')

show(p)
```

I am using bokeh v1.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for `y_range` is `"auto"` so if you don't specify any range it will scale with your extra range. The solution is to explicitly specify the `y_range` for your plot like below (work for Bokeh v1.0.4)

```
from numpy import sin
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, figure, show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, DataRange1d

x = [p / 100 for p in range(0, 320)]
y = sin(x).tolist()

output_file("twin_axis.html")

p = figure(y_range = Range1d(start = 0, end = 1))
p.line(x, y, color = "red")

x1 = [0, 1.0, 2.2, 3.2]
y1 = [60, 70, 70, 70]  # Changing these values affects first y-axis scale
p.extra_y_ranges = {"Yield": Range1d(start = 0, end = 50)}  # tried DataRange1d(), no help
p.circle(x = x1, y = y1, color = "blue", y_range_name = "Yield")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name = "Yield", axis_label = "Yield(%)"), 'right')

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]